# How to get root Url from within App_Start code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webactivator

I'm trying to preload the output cache in mvc4 application using WebActivator.  I figured I could simply make an async call to a few routes and that would do the trick.  Unfortunately, I can't find the Root Url to my app anywhere...  There is no current httpRequest.

Here is what I'd like to do.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MaidBrigade.Web.App_Start.CacheLoader), "Load")]
namespace MaidBrigade.Web.App_Start
{
  public class CacheLoader
  {
    public static void Load()
    {
      var client = new HttpClient();
      var root = ""; // Where can a fetch this from?      
      client.GetAsync(root + "/vision/marketing/NationalReportData");

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
var root = Url.Content("~/");
```

or:

```
var root = Url.Content("~");
```

Also try:

```
string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, urlHelper.Content("~"));
```

And if Request is not available, try:

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Comment: well, I didn't think that I would have an HttpContext.Current but, in fact, I did.  Thx!